# GitHub Actionsでリリースページを作成した際、pyinstallerで生成したexeファイルをリリースページにアップロードしたい

Tags: github, github-actions

## やりたいこと

PythonでCLIツールを作成しています。
WindowsでもCLIを簡単に実行できるようにするため、[pyinstaller](https://www.pyinstaller.org/)で生成したexeファイルをGitHubのリリースページにアップロードしたいです。

リリースページは手動で作成しています。
したがって、リリースをpublishした際に、そのリリースにexeファイルをアップロードしたいです。

## 参考サイト

[GitHub Actionsが便利すぎた](https://tkgstrator.work/posts/2021/05/06/githubactions.html)

## 質問

`actions/upload-release-asset@v1`の`upload_url`に渡すURLは、どのように取得すればよいでしょうか？
手動でリリースしているため、上記サイトのようにURLを取得できませんでした。

上記サイトのように、バージョンタグをpushした際にリリースページを作成する運用に変えた方ががよいのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`actions/upload-release-asset`](https://github.com/actions/upload-release-asset)は現在メンテナンスされていません。そのことを認識した上でお使いください。

---

> リリースをpublishした際に、そのリリースにexeファイルをアップロードしたい

`github.event.release`には[Create a release](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#create-a-release)のResponseが含まれています。そのため、`${{github.event.release.upload_url}}`で参照できます。関係しそうなところを抜き出すとこんな感じになります。

```
on:
  release:
    types:
    - published
jobs:
  build:
    steps:
    - name: ...
      uses: actions/upload-release-asset@v1
      env:
        GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN}}
      with:
        upload_url: ${{github.event.release.upload_url}}
        asset_path: ...
        asset_name: ...
        asset_content_type: ...
```

ちなみにffftpのリリースは同様の方式を採用していますので、[当該Workflow](https://github.com/ffftp/ffftp/blob/master/.github/workflows/main.yml)が参考になるかもしれません。